# I can't mark my own question with a correct answer as a new user, is that a good idea?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

I am a new user and I asked a question and there is a correct answer but I can't even set the correct answer for my question.

What is the wisdom behind this?

Should I be able to set the correct answer on my own question as a new user?

Answer (score 9):

You will be able to as soon as the time period elapses for allowing you to accept the answer. There is a 15 minute window where you cannot accept.

[How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Comment: No it says I need 15 points.

Comment: accept and upvote are different

Comment: No @valid_where_void, that is for up voting only. You can accept (click the check mark next to the correct answer) with any rep points.